# Programmatically add Fragment to an Activity in Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, kotlin

I have built a fragment that I wish to place on an activity.

So far, my code looks like this:

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var teamInfoModule: TeamInfoModule;

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        DaggerServiceModuleComponent.create().inject(this)

        val bundle = Bundle()
        val teamArrayList: ArrayList<Team> = this.teamInfoModule.getAllTeamData()
        val homeFragment = HomeFragment()

        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("teamData", teamArrayList)
        homeFragment.arguments = bundle

        val fragmentManager: FragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        val fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.home_fragment, homeFragment).commit()
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main">
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

HomeFragment.kt

```
class HomeFragment @Inject constructor(): Fragment() {

    lateinit var team: Team

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

        DaggerServiceModuleComponent.create().inject(this)

        val binding: ViewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ViewDataBinding>(inflater, R.layout.layout_home, container, false)
        print(arguments.toString())
        val allTeams: ArrayList<Team> = arguments?.get("teamData") as ArrayList<Team>

        this.team = allTeams[0]

        binding.setVariable(BR.team, team)

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

layout_home.xml (tied to HomeFragment)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="team"
            type="com.example.bluelightlite.models.Team" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".fragments.HomeFragment">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@{team.name}"/>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

When it runs, I get the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.bluelightlite, PID: 10421
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f07003a (com.example.bluelightlite:id/activity_main) for fragment HomeFragment{4b02ab3 (55c458bd-2931-48c6-8087-5e82641313c1) id=0x7f07003a}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception says you are trying to add the Fragment to be associated with a view that doesn't exist. In fact, I'm not sure where `R.id.home_fragment` comes from.

Solution is this:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/root_container">
</FrameLayout>
```

Then

```
if(savedInstanceState == null) { // initial transaction should be wrapped like this
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.root_container, homeFragment)
           .commitAllowingStateLoss()
}
```

So the other answer was also correct that said to use `container` and `R.id.container`, but you are also missing `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

Comment: PERFECT!!! thank you so much, I think everyone's answer was correct here but no one mentioned the setContentView... Set as accepted answer

Comment: Can use androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView right instead of FrameLayout?

Comment: Sure, if you want

Answer (score 8):

Add fragment to Activity

```
private fun addFragmentToActivity(fragment: Fragment?){

    if (fragment == null) return
    val fm = supportFragmentManager
    val tr = fm.beginTransaction()
    tr.add(R.id.framlayout, fragment)
    tr.commitAllowingStateLoss()
    curFragment = fragment
}
```

Add Fragment in Fragment

```
private fun addFragmentToFragment(fragment: Fragment){

 val ft = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    ft.add(R.id.framlayout, fragment, fragment.javaClass.name)
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss()
}
```

Comment: Try not to keep a `curFragment` unless you also initialize it in `onCreate` via the currently known active `findFragmentByTag`.

Answer (score 2):

replace this line with container id like this

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, homeFragment).commit()
```

and add framelayout in your mainactivity xml

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    />
```

Comment: Hey, 
I've done as you've said but now I'm getting the same error 

```
No view found for id 0x7f070049 (com.example.bluelightlite:id/container) for fragment HomeFragment{4b02ab3 (6dc9e25c-d62f-4ef7-a264-2ef39a773b5a) id=0x7f070049}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your fragment an id and reference it in the activity layout. E.g:

```xml
<fragment   android:name=com.example.bluelightlite.models.Team"
            android:id="@+id/Team"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```